# How to make a JobService run after an initial delay?

Tags: java, android, jobs, android-jobscheduler

I want to have a JobScheduler schedule a job to run after 5 minutes, and then it will continue to run every 3 minutes. How can i schedule a job with an initial delay?

My current code:

```
JobInfo.Builder builder = new JobInfo.Builder(32, componentName);
        if ( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            builder.setPeriodic(SUBSEQUENT_EXECUTION_INTERVAL);
        } else {
            builder.setMinimumLatency(SUBSEQUENT_EXECUTION_INTERVAL);
        }
        JobScheduler jobScheduler = (JobScheduler) context.getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
        jobScheduler.schedule(builder.build());
```

Comment: for very first time use handler with 5 mins interval and next time use timer task or alarm manager to run your job scheduler in specific time interval.

Comment: @Radhey Purpose of me using jobscheduler is because I am using background services with Android O.

Answer (score 0):

Well the ideal situation at this time is to use Android Arch's WorkManager. With this you can set an overrideDeadline that runs your task after an initial delay. More info can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/basics)